# Can cross language translations be asked here?

Tags: discussion

it's hard to find a resource where a person can ask for a most appropriate translation from a phrase in one language to another, do you think we can ask questions of this sort in here?

Comment: Translation isn't allowed for good reasons. If any of the language sites allowed translation questions, they would've devolved into meaningless translation requests of essays. (The translation tag exists in a restricted way on some sites like ELL; check out the questions in the tag before asking a question)

Answer (score 6):

## No

That's about learning a specific piece of information within Language Learning. Not about Language Learning in general.

We're not a *which is the best* translation service.

Questions that are a little more on-topic might look like:

- *How do I remember the best translation out of multiple*
- *How do I learn the best translation for things*

The major difference there being that it's not about a specific thing, sure you might provide some example like "*I'm learning Japanese and I find it hard to remember which "politeness setting" to use in conversations*" but there you're not asking direct questions about those specific cases, you're asking a more general question.

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

This site is intended for questions about methods and techniques for learning languages, which has nothing to do with cross language translations.

Answer (score 4):

## No.

Questions solely about translating are not on topic here as these questions are not about the ways to learn/teach a language. Now of course, questions about how to translate and stuff like that should be on-topic here.

Comment: I find it hilariously coincidental that you, @Flimzy, and me all answered this question within one minute of each other.

Comment: @fi12: Great minds, and all ;)

Comment: Why is your "no" not in super-bold heading mode? >:/

Answer (score 3):

Asking for translations is absolutely off-topic here.

However, asking for resources where you can find translation help is completely on-topic!